# DataCloneError: #<Promise> could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using worker thread in node js, below is my code in two files

`worker.js`

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const { 
v1: uuidv1,
v4: uuidv4,
} = require('uuid');
const {parentPort, workerData} = require("worker_threads");

const dayjs = require('dayjs');

parentPort.postMessage(getRdvSlots(workerData.data));

async function getRdvSlots(data){
  if(data.duration == 0 || data.address_id.trim() === "" || data.reasonId.trim() === "" || data.people_id.trim() === "" ){
    return false;
  }
  let details = {};

  let startDate = data.sel_date;
  details["startDate"] = startDate;

  let availableDates = await generateAvailableDates(data.people_id, data.address_id, data.reasonId, startDate);

  let emptyAvailabilities = 0;
  let slots = {};
  for(let key in availableDates){
    slots[key] = await getSlots(key, availableDates[key],data.people_id, data.duration);
  }
  details["slots"] = slots;

  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(details));
}
```

And in index.js

```
app.get("/checkworker", async (req, res) => {
    const worker = new Worker("./worker.js", {workerData: {data: req.query}});

    worker.once("message", result => {
        console.log(`${result}`);
        res.send(result);
    });

    worker.on("error", error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

    worker.on("exit", exitCode => {
        console.log(`It exited with code ${exitCode}`);
    })
});
```

In this I am getting error of

> DataCloneError: # could not be cloned.
> at Object. \worker.js:10:12

which is at line `parentPort.postMessage(getRdvSlots(workerData.data));` in worker.js

I am new to nodejs worker thread any help what is error in my code

Answer (score 3):

I found this question b/c I had the same issue.
I just fixed it :)
The object I was trying to post to the other thread had a property an async method was setting. I did not add await to the line :)

I think this will fix your issue:

```
parentPort.postMessage(await getRdvSlots(workerData.data));
```

Comment: It cause the error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Getting the same error. Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: hm this is not working

Comment: remember if you are using an async function it needs to be inside of an async function.

async myFunc(){

parentPort.postMessage(await getRdvSlots(workerData.data));

}

Not sure if that was the issue or not.